# Writing Spark Dataframe as ORC file throws error

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, orc

I'm trying to write a Spark DF as ORC file, it throws below error. I'm getting IndexOutOfBoundsException..

**Log:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 116, Size: 116
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct$OrcStructInspector.<init>(OrcStruct.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct.createObjectInspector(OrcStruct.java:549)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde.initialize(OrcSerde.java:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.OrcSerializer.<init>(OrcFileFormat.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.OrcOutputWriter.<init>(OrcFileFormat.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.OrcFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(OrcFileFormat.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask$$newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:449)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:438)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.AbstractScalaRowIterator.foreach(AbstractScalaRowIterator.scala:26)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1371)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:259)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you add more details as to how you are attempting to write to ORC?

General practice is if you are reading in data with schema such as a hive table in text format. You will use the direct api as below

```
df.write.format(‘orc’).save(‘/tmp/output’)
```

If you don’t have a schema, cases where you are reading data directly from hdfs or a streaming application. You have to define your schema and create the dataframe.

```
spark.read.csv(path, schema)
Val schema = StructType([
StructField(‘colName1’, StringType(), false)
])
```

Or if you have an RDD, you have to convert the RDD[ANY] to RDD[Row] of rows and define schema and convert it to dataframe.

```
df = spark.convertDataFrame(rdd_of_rows, schema)
df.write.format('orc').save('/tmp/output')
```

Comment: small correction: on PySpark side it should be: df.write.format('orc').save(output_path) write is not a method